# Slider won't close

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following:

```js
// Menu
function openNav() {
  document.querySelector("div.slider").style.width = "250px";
    document.querySelector("div.slider").style.boxShadow = "-2px 0px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)";
}
function closeNav() {
  document.querySelector("div.slider").style.width = "0";
    document.querySelector("div.slider").style.boxShadow = "";
}
```

```html
<nav>
            <a href="index.html"><div class="logo"></div></a>
            <div class="menu" onclick="openNav()">
                <div class="slider">
                    <a href='#Home' onclick="closeNav()">Home</a>
                    <a href="#Services" onclick="closeNav()">Services</a>
                    <a href="#Portfolio" onclick="closeNav()">Portfolio</a>
                    <a href="#Team" onclick="closeNav()">Team</a>
                    <a href="#Contact" onclick="closeNav()">Contact</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

The slider will not close. I have also tried setting it up so that if I click outside of the div it will close but it isn't working. If I run 'closeNav()' in the console the nav closes fine but I can't seem to get the onclick to work.

Comment: Clicking on any link within `.menu` is still firing a click event on `.menu` which means your `openNav` code overrides your `closeNav` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong in your code is that you're calling both method at the same time. When you click a menu item, both `closeNav` and `openNav` are called in this order, hence you'll always see it open. You can notice by adding a `console.log("open")` and `console.log("close")` in your methods. This happens because if you click on a menu item, you're also clicking the menu behind :)

You should consider using a `CSS` class and `classList.toggle("open-nav")`. See the example below:

```js
function toggleNav() {
  document.querySelector("div.slider").classList.toggle("open-nav");
}
```

```css
.open-nav {
  width: 250px;
  box-shadow: -2px 0px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<nav>
            <a href="index.html"><div class="logo"></div></a>
            <div class="menu" onclick="toggleNav()">
                <div class="slider">
                    <a href='#Home'>Home</a>
                    <a href="#Services">Services</a>
                    <a href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    <a href="#Team">Team</a>
                    <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Events propagate or "bubble"](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) so when you click a link, you call the `closeNav` function, but then that `click` event bubbles up to the parent menu where `openNav` is called.

**A few things to rework here:**

- [Don't do your event handling with HTML attributes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) Separate your
  event handling into JavaScript.
- Don't set inline styles if you can help it, they become difficult to
  override later. Separate your CSS from your HTML.
- You only need one function here. Start with the menu items hidden as
  their default styling and then just toggle that as needed with a
  toggle function.
- You can leverage event bubbling by doing [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). Just set
  your event handler on the parent of all the possible clicked items
  and let the event bubble up to that parent. Then check the
  `event.target` to see if the source was something that you need to
  act upon.

```js
// Get your DOM references just once
let slider = document.querySelector("div.slider");

// Do all your event binding in JavaScript, not with HTML attributes
document.querySelector("div.menu").addEventListener("click", toggleNav);
slider.addEventListener("click", toggleNav);

function toggleNav(event) {
  // Check to see if the click came from a link or the menu
  if(event.target.classList.contains("link")){
    slider.classList.add("hidden");  // Link: reinstate the hidden class
  } else {
    slider.classList.remove("hidden"); // Menu: remove the hidden class
  }
}
```

```css
.slider {
  width:250px;
  box-shadow: -2px 0px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)
}
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="index.html"><div class="logo"></div></a>
  <div class="menu">MENU
     <div class="slider hidden">
        <a class="link" href='#Home'>Home</a>
        <a class="link" href="#Services">Services</a>
        <a class="link" href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        <a class="link" href="#Team">Team</a>
        <a class="link" href="#Contact">Contact</a>
     </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: With this I receive the following error `script.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Comment: @Mac Whatever DOM query you called `.addEventListener()` on didn't return a DOM node. Make sure the `script` is placed just before the closing `body` tag in your HTML so that by the time it runs, all elements have been parsed into memory.